# replace \n from tag attribute using javascript regex with empty character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tag like **<span style="font-size:10.5pt;\nfont-family:\nKaiTi">** and I want to replace \n within tag with empty character.
Note: Tag could be anything(not fixed)
I want regex expression to replace the same in the javascript.

Comment: Regex on html ... don't. There's far better methods to deal with this. Assuming this is in the browser of course

Comment: @JaromandaX could u please suggest some better methods

Comment: Are they actual line feed characters or literally \ and n?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to strip out the \n character before applying this HTML to the page.

Having said that,  try this `(\\n)`

You can see it here: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3RidTq/1)

Edit: A bit of refinement and I have this `(\W\\n)`.  It works with the example you provided.  It breaks down if you have spaces in the body of the tags (`<span> \n </span>`).

I've tried everything I know to do.  Perhaps someone with more regex experience can assist?

Comment: This will also remove \n which are not part of tags. I want to replace \n only within the tag. like <span style="font-size:10.5pt;\nfont-family:\nKaiTi"> test\n test </span>. so the output will be <span style="font-size:10.5pt;font-family:KaiTi"> test\n test </span>